# Same subject and object in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

is it possible to make a query in SPARQL to find relationships where subject and object are the same entity?

Let's say I have these triples:

bob loves sam
sam loves jon 
bob loves bob

can I ask something like

SELECT ?a
WHERE { ?a loves ?a . }

Thanks

Comment: Yes that should work just fine, why don't you try it out for yourself?

Comment: Probably I should narrow down my question. I didn't find any documentation preventing this, but neither explaining this was possible. I tried it on a local copy of BrightstarDB and this didn't work. But I just tried this [here](http://sparql.carsten.io/) using services.data.gov.uk endpoint and it is working. So I will move this question to BrightstarDB forums. Thanks @RobV